# Jquery and hidden button

Tags: jquery, .net

I'm using Jquery to make some charts. I need to fire some code behind to grab the new information and have seen suggestions to use the click event of a button. So I've added a button and used it's click event to trigger the data process and works great.

Just tried to set the button visible to false because I don't need it other than it's click event and it doesn't work. So looks like Jquery can't see the button if it's visibility is set to false.

So 2 questions really:

1. Is there a work around for this, or is there a better way to call code behind using Jquery?
2. What are the tricks that you guys use to fire server side code from Jquery.

Comment: Try posting some code or at least an example of what you're doing ?

Comment: have you tried $('#btnId').hide();?

Comment: use jquery hide method. $('#button').hide();

Comment: you want show it again call $('#button').show();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess  you are talking about hiding the button *control* by setting it's `.net` `Visible` property to `false` NOT hiding with the CSS `visibility` property?

`<asp:Button id="someButton" Visible="false" />`

If this is so, the button will not be generated at all on the front end.

Set `visible` to `true` on your control then hide with CSS:

```
#someButton {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't realise that the .net visibility caused the control to not be generated at the front end.  I assumed that it was still there just couldn't see it much like the css does.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly does jquery see hidden buttons or not (I think it looks at dom model, not to styles). Maybe you would like to do something like

```
button_tag {
  opacity: 0.05 (maybe 0.0)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery you can do this too:
To show a div: 
`$('IDorCLASS').show();`
To hide a div:
`$('IDorCLASS').hide();`
If your want to hide your button on start up you can also do this:

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $('IDorCLASS').hide();
        });
```

And to show your button you do:

```
$( "#target" ).click(function() {
  $('IDorCLASS').show();
```

});
Or you can do something that other people have suggested here e.g:
`<asp:Button id="someButton" style="display:none;" />`
And using jquery just say `$('#someButton').show();`